# Работа с ораклом из виртуальной машины Win

Tags: php, linux, oracle, windows-7

Решаю задачу великого воссоединения веб-сервера с ораклом.

В двух словах ситуация: есть операционка линукс debian 8.7. На нее я поставил VMware и в эту виртуальную машину установил винду 7. А в винде 7, я поставил веб-сервер Open-Server. Потом мне нужно связать апаче и php веб-сервера с базой оракла, которая работает на удаленном компе в сети организации.

Для этого я шаманю:

1) в php.ini отредактировал данные, чтобы было подключение модулей для работы с ораклом.

```
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  
extension=php_openssl.dll


[OCI8]
oci8.privileged_connect = On
oci8.max_persistent = -1
oci8.persistent_timeout = -1
oci8.ping_interval = 60
oci8.statement_cache_size = 20
oci8.default_prefetch = 100
oci8.old_oci_close_semantics = Off
```

2) скачал из сети инсталляторы-интеграторы для php библиотеки. 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html
там я скачал: Instant Client Package и Instant Client Package - SQL*Plus.

3) Затем в настройках апаче, я проверил пути подключения php-модулей.

4) Создал переменные среды для винды, в которой записаны такие данные: `(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ip_oracle_server )(PORT = 1521)) (service_name = имя_базы)))`

5) Затем я тестировал в sql-plus подключение, там подключение было успешным. Когда же я создаю файлик php для тестирования подключения:

```
<?php
echo "Здесь идет тестирование Оракла сервера!";
$user = 'имя юзера';
$pwd = 'пароль';
$domain = 'ip_address/name_base';
$desc = '(DESCRIPTION = 
             (ADDRESS = 
               (PROTOCOL = TCP)
               (HOST = ip_server)
               (PORT = 1521)
             ) 
             (
               CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = name_base)
             )
          )'; 
// ociinternaldebug(1);
//$conn = oci_connect($user, $pwd, $domain);
$conn = oci_new_connect($user, $pwd, $desc);
```

То данная, талмуда не подключается, пишет ошибки подключения к базе, так как неверный пароль или логин. В чем проблема может быть? Подскажите, товарищи по клавиатуре).

Короче, я тут подустал немного, из-за многочисленных препятствий. Линукс практически не знаю, поверхностно. Объединять оракл с веб-сервером не приходилось раньше также. Потому прошу совета или дельной инструкции по шагам, как решить данную проблему.

Comment: Странно, что ругается на пользователя/пароль. Oracle такую ошибку может вернуть только в случае если действительно не подошел пароль. На любые другие проблемы с соединением он возвращает другие ошибки

Comment: Я тоже так думал... Потому что если бы сервер не отвечал, то ошибка бы была соответственная. Я сейчас переменные среды правлю и TNSNAMES.ora редактирую, потому что других у меня решений нет и причин ошибки. Мне подсказывает ораклист, что надо именно это менять. Потому я сижу ищу, может что еще дельное подскажете?

Comment: У вас пароль случайно $ не содержит?